# Improvements to the base R graphics

Tags: graphics, r

When I'm generating graphics for publications and talks, I tend to use `ggplot2`. However, for very large data sets where I want to generate a quick plot or for courses where students don't have a good grounding in R, I use the base graphics.

Are there any nice (simple!) ways of spicing up R graphics? For example, do you use a nice combination of colours and line types. I tend to do something like:

```
#Functional but not that nice    
plot(x1,y1, type="l")
lines(x2, y2, col=2, lty=2)
```

In particular, I'm thinking about the `plot`, `hist`, and `density` functions, but I suppose this question applies to all base R graphics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Learn to use `par`.  At the very least, make the y-axis label horizontal with `par(las = 1)`.  Manually adjusting margins with the `mar` and `oma` settings of `par` are also useful.

Use hue-chroma-luminance (HCL) colours, via the `vcd` package, especially for plots involving area (histograms or whatever).

---

The first half of Paul Murrell's [R Graphics](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html) gives you advice on customising base graphics.  If you want more general advice on drawing good graphs, Stephen Few's [Now You See It](http://www.perceptualedge.com/library.php) is my personal favourite, and Edward Tufte's [books](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) are all staples.

---

As an alternative to teaching `base` graphics, you could use `latticist` to make `lattice` easier to learn.

Comment: the `RColorBrewer` package is nice too.

Answer (score 2):

I often skip position 3 in the default palette (green) because it generates dichromat-unfriendly plots. I should probably use `palette(palette()[c(1:2,4:8,3)])` to do this automatically, but I tend to just do it by hand.  I recommend the `RColorBrewer` package too.

Andrew Gelman (a pretty well-known statistician at Columbia with a very entertaining blog) [would like you to adjust the margin and tick spacing](http://andrewgelman.com/2010/10/could_someone_p/).